# simplexml_load_file not able to fetch data from a URL

Tags: php, url, parameters, urlencode

I am using `simplexml_load_file` function to fetch data from a URL which contains XML content. There are few parameters in URL and `simplexml_load_file` is working correctly normally.

But there are few parameters which contains `&` and for these `simplexml_load_file` function is not working. This is my code. I tried `urlencoding` function but even this one is not working. This is how my code look like

```
$api_url = urlencode($api_url);
$xml = simplexml_load_file($api_url);
```

This is how URL look like

```
https://atlas.atdw-online.com.au/api/atlas/products?key=MYKEY&ar=Merimbula & Sapphire Coast&cats=ATTRACTION&size=10
```

In above URL you can see parameter ar has value which contains & and `simplexml_load_file` is not working for these type of parameters.
Any suggestion regarding this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in your URL, the ampersand (&) has two functions:

- As a separator for [URL parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).
- As a character that is part of the value of such a parameter.

To avoid the ambiguity that is presented in your question, you generally [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the URL parameter values.

You would then do something like `$ar = urlencode('Merimbula & Sapphire Coast');`. If you have no control over how the `ar` parameter is constructed, then you'll have to remove the ampersand from "Merimbula & Sapphire Coast" and replace it with something else (like 'and').

Comment: Instead of implementing urlencode function on complete URL, I implemented this on a parameter and it has worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Yes you wouldn't do this on the whole URL, because then you'd escape the parameter separators as well, rendering the URL unusable again. :) Good to know you got it working.